# Git line endings for Windows development and linux deployment

Tags: java, linux, windows, git, core.autocrlf

At this point I feel like I've read every article online about core.autocrfl and the various ways to specify line endings in `.gitattributes`, but I still can't really figure out what *I need*.

Our entire team develops on Windows, and our application is deployed to Linux.  I want to control the whole policy using `.gitattributes` so that no one has to worry about changing their settings.  The current configuration of my `.gitattributes` file is below, slightly modified from [this git repo](https://github.com/Danimoth/gitattributes/blob/master/Java.gitattributes)

We have a Java project and develop in Eclipse, so viewing files in LF endings isn't an issue.  Currently, I am not positive, but I would imagine we have mixed endings in the repository.

My goal is:

1. Developers do not have to worry about changing settings in Git, etc.
2. Cloning the repository should not leave it in a modified state due
   to line ending changes automatically performed at checkout, thus
   asking the developer to commit a file he/she did not change
3. Our Jenkins server is on Linux.  When it clones the repository, it should also not have a modified state

I changed the `.gitattributes` file to the below and deleted the index, and I now have over 3000 files pending commit due to the line endings.  If I commit this, will my problems be solved going forward, and will my above requirements be met?

```
# Handle line endings automatically for files detected as text
# and leave all files detected as binary untouched.
* text=auto

#
# The above will handle all files NOT found below
#
# These files are text and should be normalized (Convert crlf => lf)
*.css text
*.df text
*.htm text
*.html text
*.java text
*.js text
*.json text
*.jsp text
*.jspf text
*.properties text
*.sh text
*.tld text
*.txt text
*.xml text
*.conf text
*.xsd text
*.jrxml text
*.vm text
*.prefs text
*.dtd text
*.crt text
*.key text
*.ccf text
*.prefs text

# These files are binary and should be left untouched
# (binary is a macro for -text -diff)
*.class binary
*.dll binary
*.ear binary
*.gif binary
*.ico binary
*.jar binary
*.jpg binary
*.jpeg binary
*.png binary
*.so binary
*.war binary
*.swf binary
*.bmp binary
*.doc binary
*.docx binary
*.dotx binary
*.pdf binary
*.xls binary
*.xlsx binary
*.xlsm binary
*.xltm binary
*.ttf binary
```

Comment: Did this work for you, or did you solve it in a different way?